# Touch the Neopixels

Tags: arduino-uno, led, hardware

I want to create a game using the individual LED "pixels" in a Neopixels 8x8 panel as a game pieces. Any ideas how I could add a touch event to each pixel?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [trellis](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-trellis-diy-open-source-led-keypad/overview).

Or put a resistive touch panel on top of the neopixels. You can connect those using 2 analog and 2 digital pins.

Comment: Trellis can only use single color LEDs. I will look into resistive touch panel.